# 'Concentrator of your provider did not respond' Problem with wired connection. Sudo pppoeconf

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, pppoe

Similar threads couldn't help with this as it's always an individual fix. WIFI connection to the modem is functioning. The Ethernet light is on on the modem.

I want to be able to connect to the internet via the Ethernet cable that is plugged into the mode.

---

```
sudo pppoeconf
```

Returns the following error

*Sorry, I scanned 2 interfaces, but the Access Concentrator of your provider did not respond. Please check your network and modem cables. Another reason for the scan failure may also be another running pppoe process which controls the modem.*

---

I've checked and pppoe is installed

```
Package: pppoeconf
Status: install ok installed
```

---

I typed sudo poff dsl-provider
& it said

```
/usr/bin/poff: No pppd is running.  None stopped.
```

---

I typed `ifconfig`

& it returned

I typed `sudo lshw -C network; sudo iwlist scanning; cat /etc/network/interfaces; cat /etc/lsb-release; lspci -nn; lsusb; uname -a; dmesg | grep ound; dmesg | grep b43; iwconfig; sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

& it returned

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 2230
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: c4
       serial: 84:a6:c8:1e:fb:2c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-56-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.1.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:30 memory:f1500000-f1501fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 07
       serial: 2c:d4:44:92:0a:7d
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0404000-f0404fff memory:f0400000-f0403fff
enp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp1s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 40:9B:CD:97:A9:DC
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=64/70  Signal level=-46 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Internet"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000011f539a15
                    Extra: Last beacon: 128ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0008496E7465726E6574
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A9C0117FFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1606000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080000000100000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080000000100000000
                    IE: Unknown: 0706474220010D10
                    IE: Unknown: DDAD0050F204104A00011010440001021057000101103B00010310470010BC329E001DD811B28601409BCD97A9DC1021001852616C696E6B20546563686E6F6C6F67792C20436F72702E1023001C52616C696E6B20576972656C6573732041636365737320506F696E74102400065254323836301042000831323334353637381054000800060050F20400011011000A44534C2D33373832545410080002218C103C0001011049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD07000C4300000000
          Cell 02 - Address: D8:47:32:86:5B:F4
                    Channel:3
                    Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)
                    Quality=28/70  Signal level=-82 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"TP-Link_5BF4"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000179ff13e18d
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2424ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000C54502D4C696E6B5F35424634
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030103
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                    IE: Unknown: 33082001020304050607
                    IE: Unknown: 33082105060708090A0B
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010010
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD310050F204104A00011010440001021047001038833092309218839C77D84732865BC4103C0001011049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AEC1117FFFF000001000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1603000700000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080100000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD07000C4300000000
          Cell 03 - Address: 8C:59:73:A0:6E:A0
                    Channel:10
                    Frequency:2.457 GHz (Channel 10)
                    Quality=33/70  Signal level=-77 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"italk-6EA0"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000001b7fef41dda
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1436ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000A6974616C6B2D36454130
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                    IE: Unknown: 03010A
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AEC1117FFFF000001000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D160A000600000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080000000100000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080000000100000000
                    IE: Unknown: 0706474220010D10
                    IE: Unknown: DDB90050F204104A0001101044000102103B00010310470010BC329E001DD811B286018C5973A06EA01021001A5A7978656C20436F6D6D756E69636174696F6E7320436F72702E1023001E5A7958454C20496E7465726E65742053686172696E6720476174657761791024000C414D47313330322D543131431042000D533138324532393030373730391054000800060050F20400011011000C414D47313330322D5431314310080002200C103C0001011049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD07000C4300000000
          Cell 04 - Address: 80:20:DA:7C:EC:AE
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=28/70  Signal level=-82 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"TALKTALK7CECB1"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000002359b086ea2
                    Extra: Last beacon: 992ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000E54414C4B54414C4B374345434231
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 0706474220010D14
                    IE: Unknown: 200100
                    IE: Unknown: 23020F00
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 0B0502000D0000
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AAD0117FFFFFF0000000000000080017800000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D160B080400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080400000000000040
                    IE: Unknown: DD9F0050F204104A0001101044000102103B00010310470010AA6C51D2F0061E7B5A48ABB31922723210210008536167656D636F6D10230010536167656D636F6D464153543533363410240007332E302D332E301042000F4E373139303938344E3030343138311054000800060050F204000110110015536167656D636F6D46415354353336342D4E373139100800022000103C0001031049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180202101C0000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
          Cell 05 - Address: 10:06:45:56:6C:84
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=30/70  Signal level=-80 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"PLUSNET-CTJQN7"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000002359d46edd4
                    Extra: Last beacon: 976ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000E504C55534E45542D43544A514E37
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 0706474220010D14
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0104
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AFC181BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D160B080400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD800050F204104A0001101044000102103B000103104700102E08E1B91EBF83CD8806250C14B473531021000842726F6164636F6D1023000842726F6164636F6D1024000631323334353610420004313233341054000800060050F20400011011000A42726F6164636F6D415010080002200C103C0001011049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180206F02C0000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [8086:0104] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1e10] (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:1e14] (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:1e16] (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM75 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e5d] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:1e03] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 [8086:0887] (rev c4)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. Name: ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge, ASM1153E SATA 6Gb/s bridge
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b302 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0138 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5138 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Linux Navaged 5.4.0-56-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 23 19:20:19 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[    0.014494] No NUMA configuration found
[    0.127263] core: PMU erratum BJ122, BV98, HSD29 worked around, HT is on
[    0.192367] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 7 devices
[    0.418914] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.04
[    0.419185] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.438902] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.04
[    0.439139] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.477994] ima: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass!
[    0.478006] ima: No architecture policies found
[    0.512811] x86/mm: Checked W+X mappings: passed, no W+X pages found.
[    0.525735] x86/mm: Checked W+X mappings: passed, no W+X pages found.
[    0.690389] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
[    0.915546] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024, bcdDevice= 0.00
[    0.915887] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.931549] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024, bcdDevice= 0.00
[    0.931858] hub 2-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.327598] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0138, bcdDevice=38.82
[    1.333315] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=0745, bcdDevice= 6.34
[    1.569495] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=55aa, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    1.613574] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b302, bcdDevice=17.14
[    1.764073] usb 2-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=07da, bcdDevice=78.69
[    4.407993] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[    6.732106] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device FJ Camera (04f2:b302)
[    6.901593] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[    6.901596] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain core
[    6.901597] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain uncore
[    7.102570] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    7.157161] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input15
[    7.157256] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input16
[    7.157354] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input17
enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Internet"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 40:9B:CD:97:A9:DC   
          Bit Rate=39 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:1245   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

Restarting networking (via systemctl): networking.service.
```

I also typed `Sudo dmsg`
but the log exceeded the maximum character allowance. [So I included it here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1J99C1oojwmZbcvR_wiKYNYou4nuttE-1K91fBS8QVI4/edit?usp=sharing)

Ubuntu 20.04.01 LTS

Comment: It's not clear what you are attempting to do. Are you saying that your ethernet connection to your router does not work? Have you set your router aside and are trying to connect directly to the ISP modem from your ethernet port? Are you trying to set up some kind of VPN connection? Or something else?

Comment: @user535733 I have an ethernet cable plugged into my ISP modem and into my laptop ethernet connection. Not trying to set up a VPN. The wireless is inconsistent and I want to connect to the internet via the cable. Sorry that that wasn't clear before!

Comment: @user535733 do you know a better way to phrase the question and tags? Not seeming to be able to get much traction on this and would like to improve it. Thanks